# Blockchain. An economist's dream?

Tags: blockchain

Suppose I was an economist wanting full knowledge of the EBS and flows of the economy; I want to know who buys from who, for how much, and I want to see who has accumulated what funds at what time. In short, I want to trace each element of this complex system we call the economy. But I don't need to know who is IBM, who is Ford, and who is Google. I "simply" need to separate IBM from Google and Ford in my analysis.

Suppose the whole economy functioned using the Blockchain, how useful is the Blockchain for my goal? And if not very useful, are there alternatives that are?

Comment: How are you going to determine when two addresses belong to the same entity?

Answer (score -1):

Blockchain by structure is a decentralised, distributed and public digital ledger that is used to record transactions across many computers, As blockchain is public everyone is able to see the blockchain content.

Your analysis could be my analysis and I will be able to separate IBM from Google..

You can't separate them if you don't know them. But with cryptography world
nothing impossible, i'm pretty sure someone with a "Big" cup of coffee will be able do it. But i'm talking about blockchain structure not programming skills.